# Indirect accessing of data frame variable in R

Tags: r, variables, frame

I have an R data.frame object called x. From R console when I do str(x), following is what I get.

> str (x)

```
'data.frame':   2776 obs. of  4 variables:



$ Date   : Factor w/ 4018 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 ...

 $ sulfate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ nitrate: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ ID     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I now **want to access values related to a particular variable**. In that process when I do **`x.$nitrate`**
I get the values corresponding to that variable (ie nitrate) properly however when I do following

```
> frame_variable <- "nitrate"
```

and **then do**

```
> x$frame_variable I get NULL
```

This **limitation is prohibiting me to use this feature in a function that I'm trying to create**.
Could somebody help here.

Thanks.

Comment: Try x[,frame_variable]

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to access columns with a variable:

```
x[, frame_variable]
```