# how to assign a character value into a variable for future use?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a df called `Alabama` in the list `rivers` and I would like to change the following from:

```
identification <- rivers$Alabama$sequence_id
```

to:

```
location = "Alabama"
identification <- rivers$location$sequence_id
```

Or something similar?  I have many dfs I want to process in this list, and I'd like to control the inputs.

Comment: This must be a duplicate but I can't immediately find anything better than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242912/indirect-accessing-of-data-frame-variable-in-r (which recommends `[,x]`-indexing: `[[x]]` is better when `x` is length-1 anyway ...  (It's hard to search for "$" and "[[ ]]")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `[[ ... ]]` for this kind of indirect indexing:

```r
location = "Alabama"
identification <- rivers[[location]]$sequence_id
```

For accessing columns of data frame `[, location]` would also work, but `[[ ... ]]` is better in any case if `location` is length-1 (i.e., a single location rather than a vector of locations) because

- it works for lists, atomic vectors, and data frames
- it always returns a vector (data frames and tibbles have different semantics for `[,]`-indexing)